# Customer Community Login User does not have Send Email Option

Tags: community, email, digital-experience

In the digital site we added the Feed Publisher in the Case page.
At first the external user didn't see it at all, so I added the "Post" action in their page layout and now they see the feed publisher, but they don't see "Email" option. Only "Post".

When I login with my admin user I do see the Email option.

The profile is custom profile based on the standard "Community Login User" and I've notice this profile doesn't have system permission called "Send Email".
The option does not even exist for the profile and if I try to provide it using permission set I'm getting an error:
**Can't assign permission set Send Email Permission to user XXX. The user license doesn't allow the permission: Send Email**

I'm wondering if this is the reason that they don't see the Email option and if it is by design for that profile? I couldn't see the relevant Salesforce documentation.

Notes:

- The deliverability is set to "All Email"
- In support settings enabled option "Enable Case Feed Actions and Feed Items"

Comment: You need CC Plus or higher. See the table in https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.users_license_types_communities.htm&type=5

Comment: Thanks. If you want, please add it as answer and I'll mark it as the correct answer.